# Clear uint3 in CUDA using cudaMemset

Tags: cuda

I've data of type uint3. My app populates member x and y once but member z many times. So, I need to clear member z before next data comes. Can it be done using cudaMemSet?

Answer (score 1):

[cudaMemset2D](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g2b3248e96aaba2241796e113d1798db3.html#g2b3248e96aaba2241796e113d1798db3) can be used to set the value.

```
int* dev_ptr = (int*)dev_uint3_ptr;
cudaMemset2D(
    dev_ptr + 2,    // offset device_ptr by 2 elements so first element is z
    sizeof(uint3),  // set pitch to size of uint3 so each increment is to next z
    0,              // set to 0
    sizeof(int),    // sizeof(z)
    elements        // number of elements in your array
    );
```

I'm not sure of the performance. You may want to consider switching from array of structures to structure of arrays.

Comment: Regarding performance, you may be better off just initializing z to zero in the first kernel that uses it.